# Beta distribution with a priors as Uniform and Pareto Distribution

Tags: bayesian, prior, beta-distribution, pareto-distribution

I am working on a bayesian programming problem which involves a Beta Posterior, which has mean (location) parameter coming from Uniform Distribution [U(0,1)] and concentration (kappa) coming from Pareto Distribution [Pareto(scale=1, alpha=1.5].

Could anyone please explain why Pareto distribution was selected in this case and how the scale/alpha params were set up, and what might be the result of this? Adding code below for reference:

```
m = numpyro.sample("m", dist.Uniform(0, 1))
kappa = numpyro.sample("kappa", dist.Pareto(1, 1.5))
num_players = at_bats.shape[0]
with numpyro.plate("num_players", num_players):
  phi_prior = dist.Beta(m * kappa, (1 - m) * kappa)
  phi = numpyro.sample("phi", phi_prior)
  return numpyro.sample("obs", dist.Binomial(at_bats, probs=phi), obs=hits)
```

Problem Statement:
We are to estimate batting average of a player (in baseball), with `at_bats` as a predictor, and hits as a target.
An `at_bats` can be a hit or a miss, so we see the Binomial distribution at the end, but the probabilities are coming from a Beta distribution which has Uniform and Pareto priors.

Dataset sample:

```
[[412 145]
 [471 144]
 [566 160]
 [320  76]
 [463 128]
 [511 140]
 [631 168]...]
```

Comment: There are many reasons to select priors, ranging from numerical convenience to theory to experience.  Nothing in this code distinguishes among those possibilities.  At best you might elicit some inspired guesses, but it's very difficult to see how anyone could objectively answer this question.

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us your sampling distribution at least.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have edited the question to include the details.